# Calculating derivative of any unknown function $f(x)$ at a fixed $x$ using finite difference method

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, matlab

Let's say I have a one variable function $f(x)$ and know its values at some given values of $x$ i.e. I have the following data

> x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>
> f(x)=[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]

where $a,b,c\cdots$ are some numerical values. With this data given, I want to write a code (preferably in MATLAB) to calculate the 1st and 2nd derivative at $x=0$ using finite difference method.

I can not think that finite difference method can be applied on this problem. But my professor told me that it can be done. My question is how?

Comment: if you want the derivative at say $x=4$, the best approximation you can get is $\frac{f(5)-f(3)}2$.

Comment: @s.harp thank you for your comment. Is there anything that I can do to get derivative at $x=0$?

Comment: Note that you don't know what $f(0)$ is, so you have a problem. Any solution will be an extrapolation of $f$ or $f'$. You could for example fit a polynomial of degree $2$ through the points $1,2,3$ and then take the derivative of the polynomial at $x=0$.